# two asterisk sttring match in TCL

Tags: string, tcl, match

Help me to decide one problem in TCL. 
By using my macros I want find string, which contains two asterisk (`**`). 
I tried to used following commands:

```
string match \*\* string_name
```

But it doesn't work. Can you explain me where I made a mistake and how to do it correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are actually passing to the interpreter is `string match ** string_name`. You need to pass the actual backslashes to the interpreter so that it then will understand two escaped asterisks, and to do that you need to add a couple more backslashes:

```
string match \\*\\* $s
```

Or use braces:

```
string match {\*\*} $s
```

Note that the above will match *only* if `$s` contains 2 asterisks, and nothing else. To allow for anything before and after the asterisks, you can use more asterisks...

```
string match {*\*\**} $s
```

There are a few other ways to check if a string has double asterisks, you can for instance use `string first` (and since this one does not support expressions, you can actually get away without having to escape anything):

```
string first ** $s
```

If you get something greater than `-1`, then `**` is present in `$s`.

Or if you happen to know some regular expressions:

```
regexp -- {\*\*} $s
```

Those are the most common I think.

Comment: This regular expression is less backslash-y: `{[*][*]}`

Comment: @glennjackman Agreed, although longer. A similar one with `{[*]{2}}`

Comment: Jerry, Thank you very much for your help! You helped me a lot!